# WCF Services for both Web Application and Ipad development

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I am in a situation where i have wcf services and which can be consumed by both web application and ipad application. So my question is, my client needs to be authenticated with user name and password, so what is the authentication method i have to follow. whether i have to use any sessionid or some thing in url to authenticate each request or is there any other method where initially pass user name and password and from then on,the wcf  take the credentials automatically once the user is authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your question is probably already answered in [WCF sessions or pass username/password per call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240373/wcf-sessions-or-pass-username-password-per-call). If that does not do the job for you, please take a look at the [Custom User Name and Password Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx).